# A Script to Eliminate Vendor Prefixes in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, vendor-prefix

Is there a script out there that I can just include on my site that will automatically throw in the vendor prefixes to CSS? I'd like to just write standard CSS so in a few years I don't have to go back and strip out the vendor prefixes.

Comment: I don't mean something that does everything, just for simple things that are the same, like transition or transform. Obviously things like gradients would be a bit complex for a script, but seeing as there are things like http://www.prefixr.com out there now, I would think a script to include on your site that just skims your css and throws in what's available would be feasible.

Comment: Given the _cascading_ nature of CSS you could include two stylesheets, the first of which follows official CSS3, and the second one of which overrides certain settings to do the vendor specific stuff you need to make it actually work. Then in future you (obviously) just remove the second stylesheet...

Comment: Ah! That's a good idea. What I've been doing is putting `/* vendor-specific */` at the bottom of each css ruleset, but that sounds like  a better way to go. Mind posting as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just found this, it looks perfect: http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/

Answer (score 2):

I dont know of a script to do this specifically but ive been writing everything in [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) instead of straight CSS. This way you can put things like gradients in mixins (kinda like functions) and then you only have to change one small set of declarations. instead of doing it over multiple files. Of course mixins in general lead to a lot of reuse not jsut for vendor declarations but for lots of things (for example i typically define a color palette and icon sets as well as grid mixins based on 960.gs).

On dynamic sites i usually set things up to compile on the server side and cache. On static sites i just use a shell script to compile the less down to css directly before i deploy.

Comment: If you're running OS X, less.app ( http://incident57.com/less/ ) is wonderful.

Comment: @djlumley: OOOOOOOH... thats slick. I doubt if ill use since even my static projects are actually built with php (code reuse) and then compiled down to static, but if you dont already have an automated build process (or arent interested in setting one up) this would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote just such a script, used in production and without dependencies: http://imsky.github.com/cssFx/

Answer (score 1):

Given the cascading nature of CSS you could include two stylesheets, the <s>first</s>*second* of which follows official CSS3, and the <s>second</s>*first* one of which overrides certain settings to do the vendor specific stuff you need to make it actually work. Then in future you (obviously) just remove the <s>second</s>*first* stylesheet...

Comment: If you're going to include the vendor prefixes in a separate file, you include this BEFORE your standard CSS so as vendor prefixes are dropped the standard declaration is rendered.

Comment: Good point. Can I pretend that that is what I meant all along? No? In any case I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: That makes the most sense for right now, maybe I'll start a project to write this script, though. I think a lot of people would like it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to eliminate vendor prefixes, unless you dislike them adding clutter to your code.

As to why they're there in the first place, this article at A List Apart http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prefix-or-posthack/ provides valuable insight. Basically, it's easier to have them then it is not to have them.

If your CSS cascades correctly like:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
```

Then when Chrome and Safari drop the vendor prefix the style will cascade naturally and you don't have to remove anything (unless you are worried about the extra bytes they add).